# Python: Metaclasses all the way down

Tags: python, metaclass, traits

I have an esoteric question involving Python metaclasses.  I am creating a Python package for web-server-side code that will make it easy to access arbitrary Python classes via client-side proxies.  My proxy-generating code needs a catalog of all of the Python classes that I want to include in my API.  To create this catalog, I am using the `__metaclass__` special attribute to put a hook into the class-creation process.  Specifically, all of the classes in the "published" API will subclass a particular base class, `PythonDirectPublic`, which itself has a `__metaclass__` that has been set up to record information about the class creation.

So far so good.  Where it gets complicated is that I want my `PythonDirectPublic` itself to inherit from a third-party class (`enthought.traits.api.HasTraits`).  This third-party class *also* uses a `__metaclass__`.

So what's the right way of managing two metaclasses?  Should my metaclass be a subclass of Enthought's metaclass?  Or should I just invoke Enthought's metaclass inside my metaclass's `__new__` method to get the type object that I will return?  Or is there some other mystical incantation to use in this particular circumstance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should my metaclass be a subclass of Enthought's metaclass?

I believe that is in fact your only choice. If the metaclass of a derived class is not a subclass of the metaclasses of all of its bases then Python will throw a TypeError when you try to create the derived class. So your metaclass for `PythonDirectPublic` should look something like

```
class DerivedMetaClass(BaseMetaClass):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        # Do your custom memory allocation here, if any

        # Now let base metaclass do its memory allocation stuff
        return BaseMetaClass.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        # Do your custom initialization here, if any
        # This, I assume, is where your catalog creation stuff takes place

        # Now let base metaclass do its initialization stuff
        super(DerivedMetaClass, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

If you don't have access to the definition of the metaclass for your third-party base class, you can replace `BaseMetaClass` with `enthought.traits.api.HasTraits.__metaclass__`. It's wordy, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, all of the classes in the "published" API will subclass a particular base class, PythonDirectPublic

Rather than adding another metaclass, you could recursively use the result of PythonDirectPublic.**subclasses**().

Comment: I'm not finding any documentation on that particular method.  Are you suggesting using HasTraits.trait_subclasses()?  That could indeed have provided an alternative approach to building the catalog.

Comment: @DanMenes I believe Dan Ellis actually refers to the `__subclasses__` method, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3862957/396967) for how to use it.

Comment: @kynan Got it. I think that would work, too.  Although its been a couple of years since i looked at this code, so I don't remember all of the wrinkles