# Celery Get List Of Registered Tasks

Tags: python, celery

Is there a way to get a list of registered tasks?

I tried:

```
celery_app.tasks.keys()
```

Which only returns built in Celery tasks like celery.chord, celery.chain etc.

Comment: have you checked out this so thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651872/how-to-get-all-tasks-and-periodic-tasks-in-celery

Answer (score 70):

For the newer versions of celery(4.0 or above), we can get registered tasks as follows.

```
from celery import current_app 
tasks = current_app.tasks.keys()
```

For older versions of celery, celery < 4, we can get registered tasks as follows.

```
from celery.task.control import  inspect
i = inspect()
i.registered_tasks()
```

This will give a dictionary of  all workers & related registered tasks.

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain.from_iterable( i.registered_tasks().values() ))
```

In case if you have multiple workers running same tasks or if you just need a set of all registered tasks, it does the job.

**Alternate Way:**

From terminal you can get a dump of registered tasks by using this command

```
celery inspect registered
```

To inspect tasks related to a specific app, you can pass app name

```
celery -A app_name inspect registered
```

Comment: Whic doesn't list all the registered tasks for some reason.

Comment: Thats weird. Not sure what's going wrong. Can you share your celery config and your tasks?

Comment: for anyone who is using Celery with Django, `celery -A {celery_app_name} inspect registered` does the trick.

Comment: @RichardKnop The problem is that all the inspection functions of Celery are based on a [broadcast](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.broadcast) method that times out if it does not receive a reply within a specific time frame. If a worker is very busy, it may not reply within the timeout, and the result you'll get from the inspection call will be as if this worker did not exist at all. (The default timeout is 1 second.)

Comment: This isn't a reliable solution, especially for testing. `i.registered_tasks()` returns None during unittests.

Answer (score 28):

With the newer versions of celery ( 4.0 and above ), the following seems to be the right way:

```
from celery import current_app

current_app.loader.import_default_modules()

tasks = list(sorted(name for name in current_app.tasks
                            if not name.startswith('celery.')))
return tasks
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly for me, whereas the accepted answer does not.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Comment: I think this returns a list of tasks(names) as strings but is it possible to return them as objects in order to access their parameters?

Answer (score 11):

In a shell, try:

```
from celery import current_app 
print(current_app.tasks.keys())
```

`current_app.tasks` has all tasks available as a dictionary.  The keys are all the names of registered tasks in the current celery app you are running.

Comment: What could be the reason my task is not showing through python, but it does through CLI `celery worker inspect registered`?