# How to create all tables defined in models using peewee

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I define a lot of model classes using peewee. `ClassName.create_table()` can generate the table,but only one table. How could I create all tables using a single statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extending coleifer's answer with the assumption that all tables are grouped in one module:

```py
import inspect
import peewee
import tables
models = [
    obj for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(
        tables, lambda obj: type(obj) == type and issubclass(obj, peewee.Model)
    )
]
peewee.create_model_tables(models)
```

Comment: Seems create_model_tables is deprecated in newer peewee versions.

Comment: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/example.html#creating-tables

Comment: Possibly, I no longer use peewee for a very long time now.

Answer (score 22):

Peewee has a helper that will create the tables in the correct order, but you still need to explicitly pass in all the models:

```
from peewee import *
db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')
db.create_tables([ModelA, ModelB, ModelC])
```

Comment: Maybe this function's docstring could appear in the API docs?

Answer (score 17):

An update for Python 3 (and everyone who comes across this question via Google like I did). If you have all models based on the main peewee Model class you can simply use:

```
import peewee    
models = peewee.Model.__subclasses__()
```

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-can-i-find-all-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name) question for the idea. They also go into more detail on how to get it to work recursively if your model is more complex.

Comment: Hands down best solution!

Comment: Fails in some instances, e.g. if using the `SqliteQueueDatabase` extension, you get an `ImproperlyConfigured` error for the `VirtualModel` model, which is used internally but not actually part of your database.

Answer (score 2):

This snipnet will create all tables which objects are defined in the current module:

```
import sys

for cls in sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.values():
    try:
        if BaseModel in cls.__bases__:
            cls.create_table()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for cls in globals().values():
    if type(cls) == peewee.BaseModel:
        try:
            cls.create_table()
        except peewee.OperationalError as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def create_all_tables():
    for cls in sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.values():
        if hasattr(cls, '__bases__') and issubclass(cls, peewee.Model):
            if cls is not BaseModel:
                cls.create_table()
```

This also works for ManyToManyField's `get_through_model()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the existing answers did not support the BaseModel pattern recommended in the [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#models-and-fields). I created a helper function to recursively find Models

```py
def all_subclasses(base: type) -> list[type]:
    return [
        cls
        for sub in base.__subclasses__()
        for cls in [sub] + all_subclasses(sub)
    ]
```

I then filtered out base models, by prefixing them with an underscore.

```py
class _BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

models = [
    sub for sub in all_subclasses(Model)
    if not sub.__name__.startswith('_')
]

db.create_tables(models)
```