# Peewee counting all objects with specific value

Tags: python, peewee

My struggle is not with creating a table, I can create a table. The problem is to populate columns based off of calculations of other tables.

I have looked at [How to create all tables defined in models using peewee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631317/how-to-create-all-tables-defined-in-models-using-peewee) and this is not helping me do summations and count etc..

I have a hypothetical database (database.db) and created these two tables:

Table 1 (from class User)

```
id name
1  Jamie
2  Sam
3  Mary
```

Table 2 (from class Sessions)

```
id SessionId
1  4121
1  4333
1  4333
3  5432
```

I simply want to create a new table using peewee:

```
id  name   sessionCount TopSession # <- (Session that appears most for the given user)
1   Jamie  3            4333
2   Sam    0            NaN
3   Mary   1            5432
4 ...
```

Each entry in Table1 and Table2 was created using `User.create(...)` or `Sessions.create(...)`

The new table should look at the data that is in the database.db (ie Table1 and Table2) and perform the calculations.

This would be simple in Pandas, but I cant seem to find a query that can do this. Please help

Comment: No, the problem I have is not with creating a table. The struggle is to get the values for ```sessionCount``` and ```TopSession``` in the desired table

Comment: Please help, this is really a simple thing that I want to do, but I cant seem to find a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I found it...

```
query = Sessions.select(fn.COUNT(Sessions.id)).where(Sessions.id==1)
count = query.scalar()
print(count)
>>> 3

# Or:
query = Sessions.select().where(Sessions.id == 1).count()
3
```

For anyone out there : )