# A Python Puzzler

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I was wandering if you have any suggestions on how I should perform the following task in python:
Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class A(object): 
    self._classes = []
    def magic(self):
        c.foo() for c in self._classes

class B(object):
    def foo():'''some cool stuff here'''

class C(B):
    def foo():'''very cool stuff'''

class D(B):
    def foo():'''very cool stuff'''
```

What I want to do is when class A is instantiated all classes of type B - (C and D) will be insantiated in self._classes, meaning _classes is [C(),D()].

The general motivation for this, is that I want the user to easily add classes without the need to know about class that uses them. Any help will be appricated.

Comment: Why not just instantiate an instance of C & D in the __init__ method of A ? I am guessing that the question is more complex than that.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 My guess is that there can also be `class E(B)`, `class F(B)` and `class SpamEggsAndHam(B)`

Comment: The above was a toy example. Suppose the class B is subclassed by 20 classes, or more over, I have no interest in touching the A class if some new instance of a subclass of B is created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Voila (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862957/15055) for `all_subclasses()`):

```
# recursively get all subclasses of a given class
def all_subclasses(cls):
    return cls.__subclasses__() + [g for s in cls.__subclasses__()
                                   for g in all_subclasses(s)]

class B(object):
    def foo(self): print '''some cool stuff here in B'''

class C(B):
    def foo(self): print '''very cool stuff in C'''

class D(B):
    def foo(self): print '''very cool stuff in D'''

class E(D):
    def foo(self): print '''very cool stuff in E'''

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._classes = [cls() for cls in all_subclasses(B)]

    def magic(self):
        for c in self._classes: c.foo()

# usage:
A().magic()
```

Output:

```
very cool stuff in C
very cool stuff in D
very cool stuff in E
```

Comment: bah you beat me by a long margin ... but great answer (+1)

Comment: This is definately some interesting stuff. When I am doing django development I use this kind of thing A LOT.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the module in question for example `modulex`, you can use `dir(modulex)` to list all the names in the module and then for each name `x` you can use `modulex.__dict__.get(x)` to get the actual object.
Then just check if it is of type of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

**In python you can store objects like other methods in list** , so first note that you need to define other class then store them in a list , also you need to using `self` as your `foo` functions argument! if you haven't subclasses you can use this :

```
class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'B'

class C(B):
    def foo(self):
        print 'C'

class D(B):
    def foo(self):
        print 'D'

class A(object):

    def __init__(self): 
     self._classes = [B(),C(),D()]
    def magic(self):
        for c in self._classes:
            c.foo() 

A().magic()
```

resoult:

```
B
C
D
```