# Get list of all NDB model names ( class names ) in GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to get the list of all NDB model names in GAE Python ?

All NDB models are Python classes which inherit from `ndb.Model`. I thought we could use this info to fetch the names of all models.

```
class BK (ndb.Model): 
    property_1 = ..
```

I tried below ( [borrowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862957/1443563) ) code but in vain :

**ATTEMPT 1**

```
logging.info ( [ cls.__name__ for cls in globals()['ndb.Model'].__subclasses__() ] )
```

It results in error :

> KeyError: 'ndb.Model'

**ATTEMPT 2**

```
logging.info ( [ cls.__name__ for cls in globals()['Model'].__subclasses__() ] )
```

It results in error :

> KeyError: 'Model'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately for you, it is far easier in this case:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class Test(ndb.Model):
    pass

print ndb.Model._kind_map
```

Produces the following output:

```
{'Test': Test<>}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Jaime's answer, there is also the [metadata API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata), which can tell you the entity kinds that have been registered in the datastore.

Comment: Sorry but I marked Jaime's answer as accepted since I later figured out that the models for which entities have not yet been created do not get listed here. I overlooked `registered in the datastore`. My bad.