# Django: MTI get list of child classes

Tags: python, django, inheritance

Is there a way to get all child classes of a django multi table inheritance?

Example:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    pass

class ChildOne(Parent):
    pass

class ChildTwo(Parent):
    pass
```

I need a classmethod which returns `[ChildOne, ChildTwo]`

BTW: This question is not about automatic down casting :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Check this link
>
> [1]:
>   [How can I find all subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-can-i-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-python)
>
> here used `__subclasses__()` method to find all subclasses of a class.