# Django iterate through model subclasses

Tags: python, django

I have following django models:

```
SALAMI_TYPES = (
    ('S', 'Spicy'),
    ('R', 'Regular')
)
CHEESES = (
    ('P', 'Parmesan'),
    ('C', 'Cheddar')
)
class Pizza(models.Model):
    size = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Pepperoni(Pizza):
    salami = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SALAMI_TYPES)

class ExtraCheese(Pizza):
    cheese = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHEESES)
```

And following questions:

1. How to iterate thought different types of pizzas? For example in menu template.
2. Where to store forms for each pizza type and how to connect them to a model.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question has to be more concrete. You can find answers for your questions just by going trough Django tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by interrogating the python class hierarchy:

[How can I find all subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-can-i-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-python)

In your case you would want to get all subclasses of 'Pizza', something like this:

```
Pizza.__subclasses__()
```