# Python - Iterate through list of classes that extend class?

Tags: python, class

I have a certain class, namely `Animal`, and several subclasses like `Dog`, `Cow`, `Lion`, etc.

`Animal` is an abstract class which has an abstract static method `eats(Food f)`.

All of these subclasses implement `eats` and, according to each animal, will either return `True` or `False`.

How can I iterate through each of those and create a new `Animal` whose type `eats` that specific food without manually typing each class?

For example, I'd like to get an object of type `Animal` that eats grass, without actually creating a new `Cow`.

Finding the subclasses of `Animal` may be one part, but I am more interested in actually iterating some sort of list of classes and running `eats` on each of them, until I find one that returns True and then create a new object of that class.

Thanks.

Comment: *“How can I iterate through each of those”* – Iterate through what? A list of foods, or a list of animals? What exactly do you want to create? New animal types? Or do you just want to collect those animal types that eat a certain kind of food?

Comment: I had a really hard time explaining my question... I'd like to get a new Cow if the food is grass, without actually typing Cow. I would need to somehow iterate through each subclass of `Animal` and pick the one that makes `eats(grass)` true (I think).

Comment: How do you want to get a new `Cow` without actually creaing a new `Cow`? You are contradicting yourself. Do you mean "without explicitly creaing a new `Cow`"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all subclasses of a given class in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-can-i-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-python)

Comment: I actually think it's more than just that, because I also need to run `eats` on each class and do a `newObj = ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could iterate over all subclasses, do the checks and then get the first one which matches:

```
def create_animal_eating(food):
    gen = (subclass for subclass in Animal.__subclasses__() if subclass.eats(food))
    subclass = next(gen, None)
    if subclass is None:
        raise ValueError("No animal eats " + repr(food))
    new_obj = subclass()
```

This essentially does exactly what you describe and thus doesn't need any explanation.

But it gets only the immediate subclasses; if you really need all subclasses no matter how deep they are nested, refer to the linked article.

Comment: Seems to be what I need. Let me test it. Thanks!

Comment: @wtf8_decode Really *more than* enough? So take depth=0 and take the `Animal` class :-P

Comment: I guess some people are simply grammar nazis... haha thanks so much !