# Iterate through module's classes (but not imports) in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x

I have a module with several classes which inherit from an import:

```
# electric_cars.py

from cars import ElectricCar

class Tesla(ElectricCar):
    name = "Tesla"

class Faraday(ElectricCar):
    name = "Faraday"

class Zoe(ElectricCar):
    name = "Zoe"
```

From a different module, I'm doing the following:

```
# initiate_cars.py

import electric_cars
import tradi_cars
import flying_cars

import inspect

cls_electric_cars = inspect.getmembers(electric_cars, inspect.isclass)
cls_tradi_cars = inspect.getmembers(tradi_cars, inspect.isclass)
cls_flying_cars = inspect.getmembers(flying_cars, inspect.isclass)

all_cars = []

for cls_car in cls_electric_cars + cls_tradi_cars + cls_flying_cars:
    # inspect.getmembers returns a list of tuples
    # with the class as each tuple's second member
    all_cars.append(cls_car[1])
```

Everything works well except for one problem: the imports of each module `electric_cars`, `tradi_cars`, `flying_cars` make their way into `all_cars`.

So that with the above code, `all_cars` begins:

```
[
    <class 'car.ElectricCar'>,       # i don't want this
    <class 'cars.electric_cars.Tesla'>,
    <class 'cars.electric_cars.Faraday'>,
    <class 'cars.electric_cars.Zoe'>,
    <class 'car.TradiCar'>,          # i don't want this
    <class 'cars.tradi_cars.Pontiac'>,
    <class 'cars.tradi_cars.Chevrolet'>,
    <class 'cars.tradi_cars.Chrysler'>,
    <class 'car.FlyingCar'>,         # i don't want this
    <class 'cars.flying_cars.SpaceX'>
]
```

Is there a way, without making a complicated parent-class loading and `issubclass` checking, to exclude the `import`s from the classes loaded by `inspect.getmembers()`?

--
*To anticipate on the you-shouldn't-do-that remarks that may arise with such a question, the end goal of this construction is to be able to simply add a class in any of `electric_cars.py`, `tradi_cars.py`, or `flying_cars.py` and have it operational without doing anything else. If you think of any other way of doing that, ideas are welcome.*

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make `all_cars = ElectricCar.__subclasses__() + TradiCar.__subclasses__() + ...`? Then you don't need to faff around with `inspect` at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that did the trick - I wasn't aware of this method! If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it (which could be useful to other people) - thanks!

Comment: If that's the answer, the question already existed: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3862310/3001761

Comment: the question you're referring is obviously exactly what I was talking about

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution would be to change how you import `ElectricCar` in the `electric_cars` module. Rather than `from cars import ElectricCar`, you could just `import cars` and then use a fully qualified name for it in your `class` statements:

```
import cars

class Tesla(cars.ElectricCar):
    ...
```

Another approach would be to write your own `predicate` value for the `inspect.getmembers` call you're doing:

```
inspect.getmembers(electric_cars, lambda x: inspect.isclass(x) and 
                                            x.__module__ == electric_cars.__name__)
```