# python - how to get a list of inner classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, inner-classes, metaclass

I'm writing a small Python application that contains a few nested classes, like the example below:

```
class SuperBar(object):
    pass

class Foo(object):
    NAME = 'this is foo'

    class Bar(SuperBar):
        MSG = 'this is how Bar handle stuff'

    class AnotherBar(SuperBar):
        MSG = 'this is how Another Bar handle stuff'
```

I'm using nested classes to create some sort of hierarchy and to provide a clean way to implement features for a parser.

At some point, I want to create a list of the inner classes. I'd like to have the following output:

```
[<class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.AnotherBar'>]
```

The question is: **What is the recommended method to get a list of inner classes in a pythonic way?**

Comment: 1. Why are you nesting classes, could you give more context on that? 2. Don't you just want all subclasses of `SuperBar` (in which case see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3862310/3001761)?

Comment: It's not enough. In the actual application I have more root classes like `Foo`, with more inner classes to complete the parsing tree. I also need to enforce that a given token found (like `Bar`) is coming in the context of the root token `Foo`. To capture this kind of hierarchy I'm using these inner classes. -- thanks

Comment: Then [edit] to give more context. It's possible you're trying to solve entirely the wrong problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get a list of inner class objects with the method below:

```
import inspect

def inner_classes_list(cls):
    return [cls_attribute for cls_attribute in cls.__dict__.values()
            if inspect.isclass(cls_attribute)
            and issubclass(cls_attribute, SuperBar)]
```

**It works**, but I'm not sure if using `__dict__` directly is a good thing to do. I'm using it because it contains the actual `class` instances that I need and seems to be portable across Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes - you can use __dict__ - it is much more common place and usefull thna using nested classes. – but there is a catch that by looking at `__dict__`  you don't  see any attribut from the superclasses. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First: I can't see how nested classes can be of any use for you. Once you have an instance `f` of `Foo`, do you realize that `f.Bar` and `f.AnotherBar` will be the same object for all instances? That is - you can't record any attribute specific from `f` on `f.Bar`, like `f.Bar.speed` - or it will collide with an attribute from another instance `g.Bar.speed`.

To overcome this, and actually, the only thing that makes sense, you'd need to have instances of `Bar` and `AnotherBar` attached to the instance `f`. These instances usually can't be declared on the class body - you have to create them on your Foo's `__init__` method.

The only thing that Bar and AntherBar can do doing there is: (1) to have a lot of class and static methods, then they work as namespaces only.

Or, if a metaclass for `SuperBar` or themselves implement the descriptor protocol - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors  - but them, you'd be much better if `superbar` itself would implement the descriptor prootocol (by having either `__get__` or `__set__` methods), and attached to Foo's body you'd have *instances*  of these classes, not the classes themselves.

That said, you came with the solution of using `__dict__` to getting the inner classes: that won't work if `Foo` itself inherit from other classes that also have nested classes. The Superclasses of `Foo` are never searched. You can have a method to either look on all classes on  Foo's `__mro__`, or simply use  `dir` and `issubclass` :

```
class Foo:
     @classmethod
     def inner_classes_list(cls):
          results = []
          for attrname in dir(cls):
              obj = getattr(cls, attrname)
              if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, SuperBar):
                   results.append(obj)
          return results
```

(If you want this to work to all classes like Foo that does not share a common base, the same code will work if it is nto declared as a class method, of course - and also, `SuperBar` can be a parameter to this function, if you have more than one nested-class hierarchy.)

Now you have this, we urge you to ask other questions saying what do you want to actually do - and to read about "descriptors" - and even "properties". Really: there is very little use one can think of to nested subclasses.