# how to display subclass names which belongs to particular superclass in [python]

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

actually I wanted to know how to display list or names of subclass which belongs to particular superclass in python. I have 1 superclass named "company" and 2 subclasses "employees" and "customers".

```
class company:
def-------
----------
print('subclass of company are %d',(?))
class customers(company):
  def--------
    -----------
class employees(company):
def---------
 ------------
```

#### what to use in place of ? mark to display subclass of superclass "company"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-can-i-find-all-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name)

Comment: @yinnonsanders thanks