# Inheritance of class variables in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, class-variables

Trying to understand oop in python I came into this situation that puzzles me, and I wasn't able to find a satisfactory explanation... 
I was building a Countable class, which has a counter attribute that counts how many instances of the class have been initialized. I want this counter to be increased also when a subclass (or subsubclass) of the given class is initialized. Here is my implementation:

```
class Countable(object):
    counter = 0
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.increment_counter()
        count(cls)
        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def increment_counter(cls):
        cls.counter += 1
        if cls.__base__ is not object:
            cls.__base__.increment_counter()
```

where `count(cls)` is there for debugging purposes, and later i write it down.

Now, let's have some subclasses of this:

```
class A(Countable):
    def __init__(self, a='a'):
        self.a = a

class B(Countable):
    def __init__(self, b='b'):
        self.b = b

class B2(B):
    def __init__(self, b2='b2'):
        self.b2 = b2

def count(cls):
    print('@{:<5}  Countables: {}  As: {}  Bs: {}  B2s: {}'
          ''.format(cls.__name__, Countable.counter, A.counter, B.counter, B2.counter))
```

when I run a code like the following:

```
a = A()
a = A()
a = A()
b = B()
b = B()
a = A()
b2 = B2()
b2 = B2()
```

I obtain the following output, which looks strange to me:

```
@A      Countables:  1  As: 1  Bs: 1  B2s: 1
@A      Countables:  2  As: 2  Bs: 2  B2s: 2
@A      Countables:  3  As: 3  Bs: 3  B2s: 3
@B      Countables:  4  As: 3  Bs: 4  B2s: 4
@B      Countables:  5  As: 3  Bs: 5  B2s: 5
@A      Countables:  6  As: 4  Bs: 5  B2s: 5
@B2     Countables:  7  As: 4  Bs: 6  B2s: 6
@B2     Countables:  8  As: 4  Bs: 7  B2s: 7
```

Why at the beginning both the counter of A and B is incrementing, despite I am calling only `A()`? And why after the first time I call `B()` it behaves like expected?

I already found out that to have a behavior like I want it is sufficient to add `counter = 0` at each subclass, but I was not able to find an explanation of why it behaves like that.... Thank you!

---

I added few debug prints, and for simplicity limited class creation to two. This is pretty strange:

```
>>> a = A()
<class '__main__.A'> incrementing
increment parent of <class '__main__.A'> as well
<class '__main__.Countable'> incrementing
@A      Counters: 1  As: 1  Bs: 1  B2s: 1
>>> B.counter
1
>>> B.counter is A.counter
True
>>> b = B()
<class '__main__.B'> incrementing
increment parent of <class '__main__.B'> as well
<class '__main__.Countable'> incrementing
@B      Counters: 2  As: 1  Bs: 2  B2s: 2
>>> B.counter is A.counter
False
```

How come when B() is not initialized yet, it points to the same variable as A.counter but after creating single object it is a different one?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. My output for `B2s` is always the same as `Bs`.

Comment: I edited your question with simplified example of the issue. This is an interesting question, hope someone can shed some light on the process

Comment: @Rawing you are right, I pasted the output of another example... now I fix it!

Comment: Are you aware that python  has `__subclasses__` which will give you the subclasses of a class? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862957/7432

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem with your code is that subclasses of `Countable` don't have their own `counter` attribute. They're merely inheriting it from `Countable`, so when `Countable`'s `counter` changes, it looks like the child class's `counter` changes as well.

Minimal example:

```
class Countable:
    counter = 0

class A(Countable):
    pass # A does not have its own counter, it shares Countable's counter

print(Countable.counter) # 0
print(A.counter) # 0

Countable.counter += 1

print(Countable.counter) # 1
print(A.counter) # 1
```

If `A` had its own `counter` attribute, everything would work as expected:

```
class Countable:
    counter = 0

class A(Countable):
    counter = 0 # A has its own counter now

print(Countable.counter) # 0
print(A.counter) # 0

Countable.counter += 1

print(Countable.counter) # 1
print(A.counter) # 0
```

But if all of these classes share the same `counter`, why do we see different numbers in the output? That's because you actually add the `counter` attribute to the child class later, with this code:

```
cls.counter += 1
```

This is equivalent to `cls.counter = cls.counter + 1`. However, it's important to understand what `cls.counter` refers to. In `cls.counter + 1`, `cls` doesn't have its own `counter` attribute yet, so this actually gives you the parent class's `counter`. Then that value is incremented, and `cls.counter = ...` adds a `counter` attribute to the child class that hasn't existed until now. It's essentially equivalent to writing `cls.counter = cls.__base__.counter + 1`. You can see this in action here:

```
class Countable:
    counter = 0

class A(Countable):
    pass

# Does A have its own counter attribute?
print('counter' in A.__dict__) # False

A.counter += 1

# Does A have its own counter attribute now?
print('counter' in A.__dict__) # True
```

---

So what's the solution to this problem? You need a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python). This gives you the possibility to give each `Countable` subclass its own `counter` attribute when it is created:

```
class CountableMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        cls.counter = 0  # each class gets its own counter

class Countable:
    __metaclass__ = CountableMeta

# in python 3 Countable would be defined like this:
#
# class Countable(metaclass=CountableMeta):
#    pass

class A(Countable):
    pass

print(Countable.counter) # 0
print(A.counter) # 0

Countable.counter += 1

print(Countable.counter) # 1
print(A.counter) # 0
```

Comment: I would just add that in Python3.6+, one can also use [`__init_subclass__() hook`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) for the same purpose (adding a `counter` attribute to each subclass).

Comment: Or (in Python 2.7.x+ and 3.x)  use a class decorator.

Comment: however, after the creation of the first object is completed (`a = A()`), I get `id(Countable.counter) == id(A.counter)`. Why does this happen if the assignment creates a new class variable for class A??

Comment: @blue_note ints are immutable, so it doesn't make much sense to check their id. What matters is not if both classes share the same int instance, it's whether `A` has its own attribute that shadows `Countable`'s. If ints were mutable, then both classes sharing the same int instance would be a problem, but they're not. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) for more info on comparing the ids of ints.

Comment: yes, but, do you mean python interns int values?? I though it happened only for strings.

Comment: @blue_note Yes, it (CPython) does that for ints between -5 and 256.