# Instantiate class based on ini config in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a situation in python, I need to Load a module and Instantiate a class based on value provided in INI config.

```
[providers]
provider=bsnl  ; provider may be bsnl/airtel/vodafone/etc..
```

In my class I am reading this value and in a class method I have to load bsnl_provider.py and has to instantiate BSNLClass. If provider changes to airtel then I have to load airtel_provider.py and has to instantiate AIRTElClass.

How can I load relevant module and instantiate relevant class?

Comment: Perhaps you should simplify the problem by exposing a mapping `{'airtel': AIRTElClass, ...}` somewhere? But it's not clear which part of the problem you're actually stuck on, or what effort you've put into solving it so far; if you want to load a module by name, for example, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/301134/3001761.

Comment: If i add mapping like that in a class level i future, if any new provider comes, again mapping has to be changed, how can i avoid that situation?

Comment: You could have some superclass/metaclass/decorator to register classes, but again that's a topic you should research as a separate problem.

Comment: can you elaborate it so that i can do research on it?

Comment: Well it depends on which method you choose, that's why I'm suggesting you do the work. For the superclass option, for example, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3862310/3001761. If you have *a specific question* about an implementation then you can ask that later, but this is currently far too broad.

Comment: currently i am doing as 
provider = config.get_provider()
p_module = importlib.import_module(provider+'_provider')
p_class = getattr(p_module, 'Manage'+provider.title()+'Class')

Comment: Then [edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Comment: I got it and i can read all the subclasses of a class. But, how can i define which class i have to instantiate it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165649/discussion-between-krishh-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: Let me extend my question, As Suggested,  I declared the dictionary with provider_modules = {'bsnl':'bsnl_sms', 'airtel':'airtel_sms'}. But, in future if i want to add one more provider, then without touching the code, who can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, you want to get the name of future class from the ini file?

```
  import ConfigParser

  config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
  config.read('providers.ini')

  try:
      provider_name = config.get("providers", "provider")
  except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
      print("Unable to find provider")
      raise
```

After that, you can create dynamically your class (without any superclass):

```
provider_class = type(provider_name.upper(), (,), {})
```

or with:

```
provider_class = type(provider_name.upper(), (MySuperClass,), {})
```

Comment: I can read the ini file, and i don't want to follow to define a module and class names.