# How to display the built-in exception hierarchy in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to have a view of the the exception hierarchy and get it displayed nicely as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

On Terminal, I get those built-in exceptions (among other things) displayed in their alphabetical order instead:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dir(__builtins__))
```

Do you know how to achieve this goal knowing that `BaseException` is the base class of all the existing exceptions?

**EDIT:**

If needed: [How to find all the subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I think the easiest way is copying that text... if you just focuses on exact built-in exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def print_classes(cls, indent):
    print('{}{}'.format(indent, cls.__name__))
    for sc in cls.__subclasses__():
        print_classes(sc, indent + "  ")


print_classes((BaseException),'')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial solution, giving you a dict with whats derived from what.

For even prettier printing you would have to do something yourself:

```
import inspect

l = [eval(x) for x in dir(__builtins__) if inspect.isclass(eval(x)) and issubclass(eval(x),BaseException)]

d = {}

for err in l:
    d[err] = err.__subclasses__()

import pprint
pprint.pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{<class 'ResourceWarning'>: [],
 <class 'BytesWarning'>: [],
 <class 'UnicodeWarning'>: [],
 <class 'ImportWarning'>: [],
 <class 'FutureWarning'>: [],
 <class 'RuntimeWarning'>: [],
 <class 'SyntaxWarning'>: [],
 <class 'PendingDeprecationWarning'>: [],
 <class 'DeprecationWarning'>: [],
 <class 'UserWarning'>: [],
 <class 'Warning'>: [<class 'UserWarning'>,
                     <class 'DeprecationWarning'>,
                     <class 'PendingDeprecationWarning'>,
                     <class 'SyntaxWarning'>,
                     <class 'RuntimeWarning'>,
                     <class 'FutureWarning'>,
                     <class 'ImportWarning'>,
                     <class 'UnicodeWarning'>,
                     <class 'BytesWarning'>,
                     <class 'ResourceWarning'>],
 <class 'BufferError'>: [],
 <class 'MemoryError'>: [],
 <class 'ReferenceError'>: [],
 <class 'SystemError'>: [<class 'encodings.CodecRegistryError'>],
 <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>: [],
 <class 'OverflowError'>: [],
 <class 'FloatingPointError'>: [],
 <class 'ArithmeticError'>: [<class 'FloatingPointError'>,
                             <class 'OverflowError'>,
                             <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>],
 <class 'AssertionError'>: [],
 <class 'UnicodeTranslateError'>: [],
 <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>: [],
 <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'>: [],
 <class 'UnicodeError'>: [<class 'UnicodeEncodeError'>,
                          <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>,
                          <class 'UnicodeTranslateError'>],
 <class 'ValueError'>: [<class 'UnicodeError'>,
                        <class 'io.UnsupportedOperation'>],
 <class 'KeyError'>: [],
 <class 'IndexError'>: [],
 <class 'LookupError'>: [<class 'IndexError'>,
                         <class 'KeyError'>,
                         <class 'encodings.CodecRegistryError'>],
 <class 'TabError'>: [],
 <class 'IndentationError'>: [<class 'TabError'>],
 <class 'SyntaxError'>: [<class 'IndentationError'>],
 <class 'AttributeError'>: [],
 <class 'UnboundLocalError'>: [],
 <class 'NameError'>: [<class 'UnboundLocalError'>],
 <class 'NotImplementedError'>: [],
 <class 'RecursionError'>: [],
 <class 'RuntimeError'>: [<class 'RecursionError'>,
                          <class 'NotImplementedError'>,
                          <class '_frozen_importlib._DeadlockError'>],
 <class 'EOFError'>: [],
 <class 'TimeoutError'>: [],
 <class 'ProcessLookupError'>: [],
 <class 'PermissionError'>: [],
 <class 'InterruptedError'>: [],
 <class 'NotADirectoryError'>: [],
 <class 'IsADirectoryError'>: [],
 <class 'FileNotFoundError'>: [],
 <class 'FileExistsError'>: [],
 <class 'ConnectionResetError'>: [],
 <class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>: [],
 <class 'ConnectionAbortedError'>: [],
 <class 'BrokenPipeError'>: [],
 <class 'ChildProcessError'>: [],
 <class 'ConnectionError'>: [<class 'BrokenPipeError'>,
                             <class 'ConnectionAbortedError'>,
                             <class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>,
                             <class 'ConnectionResetError'>],
 <class 'BlockingIOError'>: [],
 <class 'OSError'>: [<class 'ConnectionError'>,
                     <class 'BlockingIOError'>,
                     <class 'ChildProcessError'>,
                     <class 'FileExistsError'>,
                     <class 'FileNotFoundError'>,
                     <class 'IsADirectoryError'>,
                     <class 'NotADirectoryError'>,
                     <class 'InterruptedError'>,
                     <class 'PermissionError'>,
                     <class 'ProcessLookupError'>,
                     <class 'TimeoutError'>,
                     <class 'io.UnsupportedOperation'>,
                     <class 'signal.ItimerError'>],
 <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>: [],
 <class 'ImportError'>: [<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>,
                         <class 'zipimport.ZipImportError'>],
 <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>: [],
 <class 'SystemExit'>: [],
 <class 'GeneratorExit'>: [],
 <class 'StopIteration'>: [],
 <class 'StopAsyncIteration'>: [],
 <class 'TypeError'>: [],
 <class 'Exception'>: [<class 'TypeError'>,
                       <class 'StopAsyncIteration'>,
                       <class 'StopIteration'>,
                       <class 'ImportError'>,
                       <class 'OSError'>,
                       <class 'EOFError'>,
                       <class 'RuntimeError'>,
                       <class 'NameError'>,
                       <class 'AttributeError'>,
                       <class 'SyntaxError'>,
                       <class 'LookupError'>,
                       <class 'ValueError'>,
                       <class 'AssertionError'>,
                       <class 'ArithmeticError'>,
                       <class 'SystemError'>,
                       <class 'ReferenceError'>,
                       <class 'BufferError'>,
                       <class 'MemoryError'>,
                       <class 'Warning'>,
                       <class 'locale.Error'>,
                       <class 'warnings._OptionError'>,
                       <class 'sre_constants.error'>,
                       <class 'sre_parse.Verbose'>,
                       <class 'tokenize.TokenError'>,
                       <class 'tokenize.StopTokenizing'>,
                       <class 'inspect.EndOfBlock'>],
 <class 'BaseException'>: [<class 'Exception'>,
                           <class 'GeneratorExit'>,
                           <class 'SystemExit'>,
                           <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>]}
```