# See all inherited classes in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, methods

So I've done a bit of research online and it seems like the `__subclasses__` method returns all the inherited classes for a python object ([relevant stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name))

On python3.8 I then tried the following:

```
class A:
    a = 1
      
class B:
    b = 2
    
class C(A, B):
    c = 3

obj = C()
print('a: ', obj.a)
print('subclasses: ', C.__subclasses__())
```

and I get out

> a:  1 
> subclasses:  []

this shows that class C successfully inherits A and B, however they don't show up with the subclasses method? So is there something I'm missing in the `__subclasses__` method, or has the method changed for python 3.8?

Comment: You have it backwards. Try `A.__subclasses__()`. (`A` and `B` are not `C`'s subclasses, they are its [_base classes_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).)

Comment: Use `C.__mro__` to get all classes that `C` inherits from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just combining the answerts from above :

1. `my_class.__subclasses__` will return the classes, which subclass from my_class
2. `C.__mro__` shows the inheritence hierarchy in your case :
   (<class '`__main__`.C'>, <class '`__main__`.A'>, <class '`__main__`.B'>, <type '`object`'>)

> ```
>   object
>    /  \
>   A    B
>    \  /
>     C
> ```

In short, `__subclasses__` goes down the object hierarchy ladder and the `__mro__` goes up. Good luck :)