# How can I get the docstring of a CSV Dialect object?

Tags: python

I have a program that lets the user choose a CSV dialect.  I wrote a bit of code to list all registered dialects and display their docstrings, but it shows the docstring for the parent class (Dialect), not the subclass (excel, excel_tab, etc).  Here's some code:

```
>>> from csv import list_dialects, get_dialect
>>> from inspect import getdoc
>>> for name in list_dialects():
...     print(name, repr(getdoc(get_dialect(name))))
...
excel 'CSV dialect\n\nThe Dialect type records CSV parsing and generation options.'
excel-tab 'CSV dialect\n\nThe Dialect type records CSV parsing and generation options.'
unix 'CSV dialect\n\nThe Dialect type records CSV parsing and generation options.'
```

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/csv.py#L54), this is what I was hoping to get:

```
excel 'Describe the usual properties of Excel-generated CSV files.'
excel-tab 'Describe the usual properties of Excel-generated TAB-delimited files.'
unix 'Describe the usual properties of Unix-generated CSV files.'
```

Comment: It might be easier to just iterate through the `__subclasses__` of `Dialect`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3862310/3001761. If you look at what `get_dialect` returns, they _are_ all instances of `_csv.Dialect`.

Comment: I'll note that `get_dialect` seems to return a value of type `Dialect`, rather than a value of any of the specific sub-classes. I'm not sure why, though `get_dialect` is implemented in C, not Python (ee https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Modules/_csv.c.), so there seems to be some detail of the dialect registry I'm not seeing.

Comment: Point is, you have an unintentional XY problem. `getdoc` *would* return the doc string of the subclass, if you actually *had* an instance of the subclass.

Comment: I changed the question since this obviously isn't an issue with subclasses.  If either of you want to change your comment to an answer, I'll accept one of them.

Comment: And it turns out that excel_tab is a subclass of excel, not Dialect, so I can't just iterate, I need to recurse through all the subclasses.

Comment: @samwyse if you keep reading down that post you can see there are snippets covering that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.get_dialect` is pretty weird. It doesn't actually return an instance of the classes you saw in the source code. In fact, it doesn't even return an instance of `csv.Dialect`!

For some reason, `csv.get_dialect` returns an instance of `_csv.Dialect`. Note the underscore - that's a *different* module and a different `Dialect` class that is not `csv.Dialect` and has no inheritance relationship with `csv.Dialect`.

Comment: Oof, I didn't even notice the point about `csv.Dialect` and `_csv.Dialecct`; I just assumed the former was (or was a wrapper) around the latter.

Comment: Looks like `register_dialect` uses `csv.Dialect` to create an instance of `_csv.Dialect`.