# How to avoid circular imports in class hierarchy located in several files?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, import

I want to create instances of several classes at runtime, based on configuration xml files which contain the specific class type and other stuff. Let's start with a simple example:

```
class ParentClass:
    @staticmethod
    def create_subclass(class_type: str, xml):
        if class_type == 'childA':
            return ChildClassA(xml)
        elif class_type == 'childB':
            return ChildClassB(xml)
        else:
            return ParentClass(xml)

    def __init__(self, xml):
        print('\nParent stuff done.')


class ChildClassA(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, xml):
        super().__init__(xml)
        print('Class A stuff done.')


class ChildClassB(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, xml):
        super().__init__(xml)
        print('Class B stuff done.')


ParentClass.create_subclass('childA', None)
ParentClass.create_subclass('childB', None)
ParentClass.create_subclass('unknown', None)
```

The output is as expected:

```
Parent stuff done.
Class A stuff done.

Parent stuff done.
Class B stuff done.

Parent stuff done.
```

As the hierarchy grows larger I want to have the parent class in a separate module and each child class in a separate module. Obviously, I need to import the parent module to the child class modules. Due to the `create subclass` method, the parent class module needs to know about the child classes. Importing those to the parent module would cause a circular import which is considered bad design.

What would be a good solution to solve this issue? Are there better ways to create the subclass instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some form of `Registry`:

```py
from typing import Dict


class Registry:
    _instance: 'Registry' = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._classes: Dict[str, type] = {}
        self._default: type = object

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls) -> 'Registry':
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = Registry()
        return cls._instance

    def register(self, name: str, cls: type) -> None:
        self._classes[name] = cls

    def set_default(self, cls: type) -> None:
        self._default = cls

    def access(self, name: str) -> type:
        cls = self._classes.get(name)
        if cls is None:
            return self._default
        return cls
```

then you can set the parent class as its default class.

```py
from .registry import Registry

class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self, xml):
        print('\nParent stuff done.')


registry = Registry.get_instance()
registry.set_default(ParentClass)
```

and submit child classes to your registry after defining them.

```py
from .registry import Registry

class ChildClassA(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, xml):
        super().__init__(xml)
        print('Class A stuff done.')

registry = Registry.get_instance()
registry.register('childA', ChildClassA)
```

```py
from .registry import Registry

class ChildClassB(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, xml):
        super().__init__(xml)
        print('Class B stuff done.')

registry = Registry.get_instance()
registry.register('childB', ChildClassB)
```

Cause your registry doesn't depend on your classes, you can use it without worrying about circulaNoticerts. notice that the `access` method returns a `type`, and you must call the constructor yourself.

```py
from .registry import Registry
registry = Registry.get_instance()

registry.access('childA')(xml=None)
# Parent stuff done.
# Class A stuff done.

registry.access('childB')(xml=None)
# Parent stuff done.
# Class B stuff done.

registry.access('unknown')(xml=None)
# Parent stuff done.
```

You can also access subclasses and their names dynamically (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name)) but since you didn't use subclass names as your key when creating subclasses, you probably need some mapping between names and subclasses. If you want your subclasses to tell your parent class the name they wish to be called by, you are implementing `Registry` in your parent class again.

accessing subclass names:

```py
print([cls.__name__ for cls in ParentClass.__subclasses__()])
# ['ChildClassA', 'ChildClassB']
```

accessing subclasses themselves:

```py
print(ParentClass.__subclasses__())
# [<class '__main__.ChildClassA'>, <class '__main__.ChildClassB'>]
```

Comment: Thank you. The registry approach looks feasible. Basically, the goal seems to be to move the functionality of the static method `create subclass` to a place outside the class to avoid cross-dependencies.

Comment: That's exactly the point!